# How to speed up my numpy loop using numpy.where()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have written a function about ordered logit model, recently.
But it takes me lots of time when running big data.
So I want to rewrite the code and substitute **numpy.where** function to **if** statement.
There have some problem about my new code, I don't know how to do it.
If you know, Please help me. Thank you very much!

**This is my original function.**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import logistic

def func(y, X, thresholds):
    ll = 0.0
    for row in zip(y, X):
        if row[0] == 0:
           ll += logistic.logcdf(thresholds[0] - row[1])
        elif row[0] == len(thresholds):
           ll += logistic.logcdf(row[1] - thresholds[-1])
        else:
           for i in xrange(1, len(thresholds)):
               if row[0] == i:
                   diff_prob = logistic.cdf(thresholds[i] - row[1]) - logistic.cdf(thresholds[i - 1] - row[1])
                   if diff_prob <= 10 ** -5:
                       ll += np.log(10 ** -5)
                   else:
                       ll += np.log(diff_prob)
     return ll
y = np.array([0, 1, 2])
X = [2, 2, 2]
thresholds = np.array([2, 3])
print func(y, X, thresholds)
```

**This is the new but not perfect code.**

```
y = np.array([0, 1, 2])
X = [2, 2, 2]
thresholds = np.array([2, 3])
ll = np.where(y == 0, logistic.logcdf(thresholds[0] - X),
          np.where(y == len(thresholds), logistic.logcdf(X - thresholds[-1]),
                   np.log(logistic.cdf(thresholds[1] - X) - logistic.cdf(thresholds[0] - X))))
print ll.sum()
```

The problem is that I don't know how to rewrite the sub-loop(**for i in xrange(1, len(thresholds)):**) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think asking how to implement it just using `np.where` is a bit of an [X/Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

So I'll try to explain how I would approach optimizing this function.

My first instinct is to get rid of the `for` loop, which was the pain point anyway:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import logistic

def func1(y, X, thresholds):
    ll = 0.0
    for row in zip(y, X):
        if row[0] == 0:
            ll += logistic.logcdf(thresholds[0] - row[1])
        elif row[0] == len(thresholds):
            ll += logistic.logcdf(row[1] - thresholds[-1])
        else:
            diff_prob = logistic.cdf(thresholds[row[0]] - row[1]) - \
                         logistic.cdf(thresholds[row[0] - 1] - row[1])
            diff_prob = 10 ** -5 if diff_prob < 10 ** -5 else diff_prob
            ll += np.log(diff_prob)
    return ll

y = np.array([0, 1, 2])
X = [2, 2, 2]
thresholds = np.array([2, 3])
print(func1(y, X, thresholds))
```

I have just replaced `i` with `row[0]`, without changing the semantics of the loop. So that's one for loop less.

Now I would like to have the *form* of the statements in the different branches of the `if-else` to be the same. To that end:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import logistic

def func2(y, X, thresholds):
    ll = 0.0

    for row in zip(y, X):
        if row[0] == 0:
            ll += logistic.logcdf(thresholds[0] - row[1])
        elif row[0] == len(thresholds):
            ll += logistic.logcdf(row[1] - thresholds[-1])
        else:
            ll += np.log(
                np.maximum(
                    10 ** -5, 
                    logistic.cdf(thresholds[row[0]] - row[1]) -
                     logistic.cdf(thresholds[row[0] - 1] - row[1])
                )
            )
    return ll

y = np.array([0, 1, 2])
X = [2, 2, 2]
thresholds = np.array([2, 3])
print(func2(y, X, thresholds))
```

Now the expression in each branch is of the form `ll += expr`.

At this piont there are a couple of different paths the optimization can take. You can try to optimize the loop away by writing it as a comprehension, but I suspect that it'll not give you much increase in speed.

An alternate path is to pull the `if` conditions out of the loop. That is what your intent with `np.where` was as well:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import logistic

def func3(y, X, thresholds):
    y_0 = y == 0
    y_end = y == len(thresholds)
    y_rest = ~(y_0 | y_end)

    ll_1 = logistic.logcdf(thresholds[0] - X[ y_0 ])
    ll_2 = logistic.logcdf(X[ y_end ] - thresholds[-1])
    ll_3 = np.log(
        np.maximum(
            10 ** -5, 
            logistic.cdf(thresholds[y[ y_rest ]] - X[ y_rest ]) -
              logistic.cdf(thresholds[ y[y_rest] - 1 ] - X[ y_rest])
        )
    )
    return np.sum(ll_1) + np.sum(ll_2) + np.sum(ll_3)

y = np.array([0, 1, 2])
X = np.array([2, 2, 2])
thresholds = np.array([2, 3])
print(func3(y, X, thresholds))
```

Note that I turned `X` into an `np.array` to be able to use fancy indexing on it.

At this point, I'd wager that it is fast enough for my purposes. However, you can stop earlier or beyond this point, depending on your requirements.

---

On my computer, I get the following results:

```
y = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, size=(10000,))
X = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, size=(10000,))
thresholds = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(10))

%timeit func(y, X, thresholds) # Original
1 loops, best of 3: 1.51 s per loop

%timeit func1(y, X, thresholds) # Removed for-loop
1 loops, best of 3: 1.46 s per loop

%timeit func2(y, X, thresholds) # Standardized if statements
1 loops, best of 3: 1.5 s per loop

%timeit func3(y, X, thresholds) # Vectorized ~ 500x improvement
100 loops, best of 3: 2.74 ms per loop
```