# Speed up numpy interpolation using for and if-else by vectorization?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization, interpolation

Recently, I discovered the bottleneck (slow-down - especially with a large 3D array input) came from a section of the code as such:

```
for i in range(0, height):
    for j in range(0, width):
        for k in range(0, color_channels):
            if k == 0:
                u = 2
            elif k==2:
                u = 0
            else:
                u = 1

            if ra[i,j,k] < cr[0, u]:
                im[i, j, k] = 0
            elif ra[i,j,k] > cr[255, u]:
                im[i, j, k] = 255
            else:
                p = np.argmin(np.abs(ra[i,j,k]-cr[:,u]))

                if ra[i,j,k] >= cr[p,u]:
                    p1 = p
                    p2 = p+1
                elif ra[i,j,k] < cr[p,u]:
                    p2 = p
                    p1 = p-1

                im[i,j,k] = (ra[i,j,k]-cr[p1,u])/(cr[p2,u]-cr[p1,u]) + p1 - 1
```

I have been thinking that the slow-down could be a result of having to access individual elements, performing if-else conditional check in each step.

Can I check if I could **vectorise** this whole fragment of code, instead of the element-wise check method now? *(meaning to compress the code as much as possible in memory, so I can get better speed improvement while still doing the same operations)*

I have thought of `np.where(ra[i,j,k] < cr[0,u], 0, 255)` or the use of a ternary operator `im[i,j,k] = 0 if rad[i,j,k] < crf[0,u] else 255....` but I am at a lost as to extending it to **if-elif-else**.

**Edited**

Input: Convert `ra[:,:,0:2]` by looking up a "table" `cr[:,0:2]`. From `k` to `u`, it's simply a flip in value that converts BGR to RGB. The border cases are at `cr[0,u]` & `cr[255,u]` where `u` is the color channel, hence further processing are done when it's `cr[0,u] < ra[i,j,k] < cr[255,u]`.

ra: (288,432,3)

```
[[[ 0.01468986  0.01744777  0.02015795]
  [ 0.01174445  0.01728123  0.01949396]
  [ 0.01320375  0.017014    0.02134987]
  ..., 
  [ 0.00914649  0.00453902  0.00635094]
  [ 0.0092403   0.00457775  0.00643213]
  [ 0.00901172  0.00452492  0.00629017]]]
```

cr: (256,3)

```
  0:[[  9.80195026e-04   6.22477547e-04   8.85527540e-04]
  1: [  1.70410880e-03   1.03346918e-03   1.51404258e-03]
     ...
254: [  1.00000000e+00   9.43613146e-01   8.04093277e-01]
255: [  1.00000000e+00   9.43613146e-01   8.04093277e-01]]
```

Output: `im[:,:,:]` - Numpy array representing a RGB image with all 3 color channels, hence the need to clip the range (0-255).

im: (288,432,3)

```
[[[ 25.89789215  31.5206012   30.38701142]
  [ 19.66823847  31.2260846   29.3507531 ]
  [ 22.74473678  30.75871397  32.40058188]
  ...,
  [ 14.79645237   7.14786503   6.78260893]
  [ 14.96887532   7.22807609   6.9330227 ]
  [ 14.54876706   7.11865354   6.6700264 ]]]
```

Comment: it's not clear what do you want to achieve eventually , it would be better if you post a sample data and desired results

Comment: @NaderHisham Thanks for ur reply. I have included some explanation on the input and expected output. Hope that helps

Comment: @NaderHisham I read that one way to speed up numpy code is to efficiently select them/slicing/broadcasting. Hence, I was wondering if the code I've given can be modified for such improvements. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788203/how-to-speed-up-my-numpy-loop-using-numpy-where but I don't quite understand the accepted answer

Comment: @ali_m I have added some examples. As much as I would like to convert the whole code, I am more concerned with the proper syntax needed to perform vectorization in place of the for loops and if statements, than getting the exact code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code transforms the values in `ra` by performing linear interpolation to get their corresponding row indices within `cr`. The whole set of nested loops could be replaced using [`np.interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html):

```
# indices between 0 and 255, corresponding to the rows of cr
idx = np.arange(cr.shape[0])

im = np.empty_like(ra)
im[..., 0] = np.interp(ra[..., 0], cr[:, 2], idx) # red
im[..., 1] = np.interp(ra[..., 1], cr[:, 1], idx) # green
im[..., 2] = np.interp(ra[..., 2], cr[:, 0], idx) # blue
```

Your code sample actually generates values between -1 and 254 because of the `- 1` on the last line, so in order to exactly match your original result you would also need to subtract 1 from `im`. Based on the wording of your question I assume that this is a mistake in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much @ali_m ! I learn a lot from your code. And yes you are right abt the -1, it's a wrong assumption I had made.

Comment: No problem. This is a good example of why you should always explain the overall problem you are trying to solve, and provide example input and output data so that other people can easily reproduce your results. Just looking at your code, it's not immediately obvious that you are trying to do interpolation.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the advice @ali_m . Will take note of these points for myself and to share with others :)

Comment: Quite impressive to come up with this solution with that little information :)